# Android: how to check when everything is loaded?

Tags: java, android

I am keeping getting Nullpointer exceptions at an extremely early android loading stage:

```
Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on 3031C2FF986F00EC
 [2013-01-13 02:53:30 - Login] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

This is because of a piece of code that I inserted into some OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper (might as well be SqliteOpenHelper I guess) subclass method that triggers this error. It seems as though the this code gets called too early in the loading process so that this happens. Unfortunately the program stops at no breakpoints this early in the loading process.

I already tested the code extensively and successfully in other code places.

So how do I know when everything is loaded in android that I can run this code without errors?

FYI: it is a piece of code that fetches database content from a server and saves it to the local sqllite database, so that the database is always in the same state (dictated by server) when I start the program.

OK I'll try an edit and post some code

```
public class DatabaseTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<UebersichtEinsaetze> {
    private DatabaseHelperBase helper;
    private UebersichtEinsaetze mainActivity;

    public DatabaseTests() {
        super("de.innosoft.android", UebersichtEinsaetze.class);
    }

    // throws exception -.-
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
```

it stops there with the unit test file. don't know where it goes from there but I know it arrives at (because it called the function somewhere in UebersichtEinsaetze and beyond where it works with a SimpleCursorFactory):

```
public <T extends Entity<T, I>, I> RuntimeExceptionDao<T, I> getRTE(Class<T> clazz) {
    RuntimeExceptionDao<T, I> rte = super.getRTE(clazz);
            initTestdata();
    return rte;
}
```

initTestdata is:

```
            if (!init)
            {
                new HttpBase(new HttpGet(), "setup", "InitTestdata").evaluate();
                if (!isTestdataUpToData())
                {
                    this.dropTables();
                    this.createTables();
                    try {
                        Map<Class<?>, List<Object>> m = ControllerMethod.GETALL.testServer();
                        for (EntityRef<?> entityRef : Entity.entities) {
                            List<Object> l = m.get(entityRef.getClazz());
                            if (entityRef.getSizeOfTestTable() != l.size())
                                throw new Exception("Testdata inconsistency");
                            for (Object entity : l) {
                                Object dao = this.getClass().getMethod("getRTE", Class.class).invoke(this, entityRef.getClazz());
                                dao.getClass().getMethod("create", Object.class).invoke(dao, entity);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
                    }
                }
                init = true;
            }
        }
```

and this is where the exception occurs. If I remove this code block and paste in somewhere directory into the unit test (e.g.) it works. But I don't want to do that.

logcat:

```
     01-13 03:32:18.594: I/dalvikvm(24888): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
01-13 03:32:18.707: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 146K, 13% free 2657K/3044K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 33ms
01-13 03:32:18.765: I/ActivityThread(24888): Pub de.innosoft.android: de.innosoft.android.test
01-13 03:32:18.816: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 164K, 13% free 2983K/3396K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 37ms
01-13 03:32:18.886: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 228K, 14% free 3222K/3720K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 23ms
01-13 03:32:18.886: D/dalvikvm(24888): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
01-13 03:32:18.914: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 245K, 16% free 3317K/3912K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
01-13 03:32:18.937: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 241K, 15% free 3411K/4008K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
01-13 03:32:19.011: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 241K, 12% free 3631K/4112K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 38ms
01-13 03:32:19.140: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 8% free 4031K/4340K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 49ms
01-13 03:32:19.265: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 324K, 12% free 4259K/4824K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 51ms
01-13 03:32:19.422: D/dalvikvm(24888): GC_CONCURRENT freed 505K, 15% free 4387K/5132K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 55ms
01-13 03:32:19.484: W/dalvikvm(24888): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lde/innosoft/android/data/Consts;
01-13 03:32:19.484: D/AndroidRuntime(24888): Shutting down VM
01-13 03:32:19.484: W/dalvikvm(24888): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db5930)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at de.innosoft.android.data.HttpBase.<init>(HttpBase.java:76)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at de.innosoft.android.data.DatabaseHelperTestdata.initTestdata(DatabaseHelperTestdata.java:46)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at de.innosoft.android.data.DatabaseHelperTestdata.getRTE(DatabaseHelperTestdata.java:75)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at de.innosoft.android.test.onCreate(test.java:66)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4969)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4582)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4524)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:150)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    at de.innosoft.android.data.Consts.<clinit>(Consts.java:36)
01-13 03:32:19.492: E/AndroidRuntime(24888):    ... 18 more
```

Comment: This looks like a unit test.  Is it?

Comment: If this is a test, could you please include the source of your test?  Android provides several base classes for testing.  If you are not using the right base class, it is possible that the Android runtime has not been initialized to a state that will support your class under test.

Comment: That would be too long, it's some pages long if I post all the called functions however I I'll post something

Comment: At least post the test class definition and other relevant parts.

Comment: Also, could you please post the entire LogCat stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but this still does not show on what line the exception is occurring.  The logcat stack trace really would help.

Comment: I'm lost. How exactly can I get the complete stacktrace. Searched google already and tried Log.e(...,...,throwable) already. Still cuts of at NullPointerException.

Comment: It's there now.  I think I was looking at an earlier edit that did not have it.

Comment: OK, so the exception is in HttpBase.java, line 76.  Have you stepped through this code to see what is going on there?

Comment: Eclipse does not stop a breakpoints this early, tried it

Comment: NPE is actually coming from Consts.java, line 36 according to the latter part of the trace, so look there for clues